# Sending Json data to server + Deserialization issue

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a service (service 1) which received a list of key value pair. . I then convert this to Json and post to another service (service 2) which serializes the data and process that as an object. Service1 does not have idea about what values will be there for a key.
e.g Service 1 gets the input Dictionary

```
Name:Sample Test:TestCase1 InnerObject:{"InnerObjectType":"1", "Name":"Sample"} TestVector
```

I use NewtonSoft.Json library to build the json to post to service 2.

```
JObject jsonData = new JObject();
Dictionary<string,string> dict = this.GetCasiPDPTestData();
foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
{
  string value = dict[key];                   
  jsonData.Add(new JProperty(key, value));
}
string postData = jsonData.ToString();
```

However, with this if the value is of type array or object, it gets translated as string and the server throws error " Failed to deserialize object data from HTTP request"

The post data looks like (Fiddler):

```
{
  "Type": "1",
  "BoolParam": "True",
  "TestVector": "[\"123\",\"456\"]",
  "Text": "Surya Test 9/23/2013 3:41",
  "Number": "44",
  "InnerData": "{\"InnerMessage\": \"InnerMessage_44\",\"Things\": [{\"AdditionalType\": \"InnerAdditionalType1_44\",\"Name\": \"InnerName1_44\",\"Version\": 44,\"Url\": \"InnerUrl1_44\",\"Image\": \"InnerImage1_44\",\"Description\": \"InnerDescription1_44\"},{\"AdditionalType\": \"InnerAdditionalType2_44\",\"Name\": \"InnerName2_44\",\"Version\": 44,\"Url\": \"InnerUrl2_44\",\"Image\": \"InnerImage2_44\",\"Description\": \"InnerDescription2_44\"}]}",
  "AdditionalType": "AdditionalType_44",
  "Name": "Surya Test 9/20/2013 4:42",
  "LastUpdatedAt": 635153176425968666,
  "Version": "45",
  "Url": "Url_44",
  "Image": "Image_44",
  "Description": "Description"
}
```

We can see the array "TestVector" and object "InnerData" are getting interpreted as string. Since service1 has no idea about the value for key, what would be the solution to parse the dictionary to create the json to post to service2. Data expected by service 2

```
{
  "Type": "1",
  "BoolParam": "True",
  "TestVector": ["123","456"],
  "Text": "Surya Test 9/23/2013 3:41",
  "Number": "44",
  "InnerData": {"InnerMessage": "InnerMessage_44","Things": [{"AdditionalType": "InnerAdditionalType1_44","Name": "InnerName1_44","Version": 44,"Url": "InnerUrl1_44","Image": "InnerImage1_44","Description": "InnerDescription1_44"},{"AdditionalType": "InnerAdditionalType2_44","Name": "InnerName2_44","Version": 44,"Url": "InnerUrl2_44","Image": "InnerImage2_44","Description": "InnerDescription2_44"}]},
  "AdditionalType": "AdditionalType_44",
  "Name": "Surya Test 9/20/2013 4:42",
  "LastUpdatedAt": 635153176425968666,
  "Version": "45",
  "Url": "Url_44",
  "Image": "Image_44",
  "Description": "Description"
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with Converter
public class KeyValuePairConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
    Member of Newtonsoft.Json.Converters